# TableView and heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, height, tableview

I want each post to display the Full title in multiple rows and each cell to have its own custom height according to the text title character number. I did this but it does not work. I think every object should be called independently. how can I make this work? here is my code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PFObject *object1 = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Posts"];
    NSString *string1 = [object1 objectForKey:@"text"];
    NSLog(@"%@",string1);



    CGSize theSize = [string1 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(265.0f, 9999.0f) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    // numberOfTextRows is an integer.

    numberOfTextRows = (round(theSize.height/14));

    if ((indexPath.row== 0) || (numberOfTextRows <2)) {
        return 44;
    }

    else {
        return theSize.height +18;
    }
}
```

Note: the NSLog shown displays (null)
thank you in advance..

Comment: Have you tried removing the logic out of heightForRowAtIndexPath method and putting in a fixed number? You could then see if your logic is causing the problem.

Comment: Well, if your log displays null, then the problem is not in the code you posted, but has something to do with object1. Is object1 null also -- try logging it and see what you get.

Comment: @rdelmar the log for object1 is <Posts:new:(null)> {}. maybe if I could make an array which will store all the values of the objects and then call them? will that work?

Comment: The other problem with this code is that string1 (if you can get it to work) will be the same each time this method is called (once for each row). You should be accessing a different string based on the indexPath each time the method is called.

Comment: "what page should I lean to?" I have no idea what this means.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Customize as you want.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellText;
    CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;

    if (searchDisplayController.active && [searchResults count]) {
        cellText = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cellText = [detailPeriodsContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(screenWidth-40, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return labelSize.height + 35;
}
```